# How to keep thousand separators (,) of decimal numbers while hiding unnecessary zeros in excel

Tags: excel

I hope someone can help me with this.  I have searched for an answer on the internet, but I have not come across with an exact answer I am looking for to solve my formating issue in Microsoft Excel.

In Excel, I would like to display numbers as below for example.

```
1,222,252.042
1,643,123
2,334,234.1
1,235.02
0.204
```

I do not want to have zeros after the smallest decimal unit. For example, 0.1 should be 0.1, not 0.100.  I do not want trailing decimal point. For example, 54 should be 54, not 54.(dot).  Also, the thousand separator should be kept. For example, 4,567 should be 4,567, not 4567.

I do not want below (more examples).

```
1,222,252.0420 
1,643,1230
2,334,234.1000
1,235.0200
0.2040
```

I do not want below, either.

```
1222252.042
16431230.
2334234.1
1235.02
0.204
```

I formatted cells with custom cell format #,###,##0.####
But, I cannot hide decimal dots when the numbers are whole numbers.
For example, 1,234 becomes 1,234.(dot).
I cannot use general format, because it will not show the thousand separators.

I would appreciate it very much if you could help me on this.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditional formatting to apply a different format for numbers without a decimal part:-

```
Highlight the range of your numbers

Go to Conditional formatting | New Rule | Use a formula

Put in (if your list of numbers starts in C2 as below)

    =C2=INT(C2)
```

with the format

```
    ###,###,##0
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Tom and Grade  Thank you for your reply.  I tried Tom's solution and it worked!  However, I have many sheets that I need to apply the same format in the same cell positions.  When I select multiple number of sheets, and try to use the Conditional Formatting button, Excel does not let me use it.  So, this means I have to manually apply the solution for each column (different columns) in each sheet....  Is there any way I can implement your solution for multiple number of sheets at one go?  Your help is highly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't think so. The only thing you can do to speed it up a bit is to use the Format Painter, but it's still a manual process.

Comment: Hi, Tom Thank you for your replies.  Ok, I must accept the manual aspect, but I also realised that your method with conditional formatting does not seem to work on the number 9,447.6...?  It comes up as 9447.6, instead of 9,447.6.  Any solution for this?  Thank you.

Comment: Hi abacus - I've tested it on 9447.6 and it works fine for me. Because this is not an integer, the conditional format formula won't apply, so you need to check that your original custom format #,###,##0.#### is set for the cell containing 9447.6 as well as my conditional format.

Comment: Hi, Tom OK, I will check.  You must be right.  Thank you very much for your help! =)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, so I'll just add to the response from @Tom Sharpe by saying that as discussed on this page http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/excel-custom-number-formats.htm there is no way to mark whether the decimal shows up or not based on the size of the number, within the custom format options. You can choose alternative formatting for positive numbers, negative numbers, zeroes, and text. Any other "variable" formatting must be based on the available character set shown in the table on ozgrid's discussion.

ie: "#,##0.###" will always show a zero, may show additional digits to the left of the zero if they exist, will always show a decimal, and may show additional digits to the right of the decimal if they exist.

Note that while you may think that this optional formatting method is possible based on how Excel reacts when you type in a number without setting formatting, that is actually Excel taking your input and deciding which format is best for your data, which is not the same thing as having a consistent format which fluctuates based on whether you have any decimals or not.

**So, if you want any other form of formatting to change, you will need to use a conditional formatting rule as noted in the answer above.**